# How can i see or how do i know where to put the control according to the screen when using css?

Tags: css, html

I'm using netbeans 8.0.1 and i have a css file with this content:

```
/* null margins and padding to give good cross-browser baseline */
html,body,address,blockquote,div,
form,fieldset,caption,
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,
hr,ul,li,ol,ul,dd,dt,dl,
table,tr,td,th,p,img {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

img,fieldset {
    border:none;
}

hr {
    display:none;
    /*
        HR in my code are for semantic breaks in topic/section, NOT
        style/presenation, so hide them from screen.css users
    */
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
    * {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
        -moz-text-size-adjust:none;
        -ms-text-size-adjust:none;
    }
}

body {
    font:normal 85%/150% "segoe ui",helvetica,sans-serif;
}

.ss_scripted img {
    display:none;
}

.ss_scripted .ss_show {
    display:block;
}

#slideShow img {
    margin:0 auto;
}

#slideCounter {
    text-align:center;
    padding:0.25em 1em;
    font:bold 200%/120% consolas,courier,monospace;
    color:#C00;
}

#slideControls {
    width:512px;
    padding:0.5em 0;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#slideControls a {
    float:left;
    padding:0.25em 0.6em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    background:#EEE;
    border:2px solid #666;
    -webkit-border-radius:1em;
    -moz-border-radius:1em;
    border-radius:1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        inset 0 -0.5em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
        0 0 1px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:
        inset 0 -0.5em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
        0 0 1px #000;
    box-shadow:
        inset 0 -0.5em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
        0 0 1px #000;
}

#slideControls a:active,
#slideControls a:focus,
#slideControls a:hover {
    background:#FFF;
}

#slideControls .next {
    float:right;
}
```

How can i see in real time where it put and change the location of the controls and other stuff ?

I can change the values and run it every time to see but that's a lot of work.

For example in c# there is a designer. That's what i mean something like a designer.

Comment: wondering why you chose a late answer that provides same info as mine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Developer Tools on Chrome. Try with F12 or right click the element you want and chose "inspect element"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can open the browser console by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.

You'll be able to spot a *styles* section under *elements* tab (*inspector* in FF), where you can change the CSS properties real time.

Following is a screenshot of chrome's console (*It's somewhat similar is all major browses*):

> [image]

---

Right clicking and choosing *inspect element* will open the console in the above mentioned tab where you can play with the styles and corresponding changes real time